# Django filter_horizontal for Many-to-One relations

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I need to create a DropDown with search field in django admin panel. After a little surfing, I found "filter_horizontal" which does something similar to what I want, but it works only for M2M relations. Any suggestions, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at django-select2 https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html . This is the app includes Select2 driven Django Widgets.

Comment: Thanks, dude! 
django_select2.Select2Widget really helped

Comment: Please mark the issue as resolved. If this is of course true)

Comment: As an alternative, I could use built-in raw_id_fields
and autocomplete_fields (Django >= 2) :)